# Pytest-django dependency injection

Tags: python, django, pytest

How does pytest-django know whether to inject a test function with a `RequestFactory` or `Client` instance?

```
def test_with_client(client):
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.content == 'Foobar'


def test_details(rf):
    request = rf.get('/customer/details')
    response = my_view(request)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

In other words: how can you make sure the input fixture is of a certain type?

Comment: Because you passed the fixture yourself.

Comment: @heeamy not sure I understand. Are you saying that it passed a `Client` instance because i named the variable `client`?

Comment: Is your question: "how can you make sure the input fixture is of a certain type"?

Comment: @heeamy yes, edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pytest doesn't inject based on type but on *name*. The name of the input parameter is matched to registered fixtures.

See the docs [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html), but in short

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def connection():
    return Connection()

def test_my_object(connection):
    target = MyObject(connection)

    assert ...
```

You can use type annotations to help PyCharm etc infer the correct type, but these are not used by pytest.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you shouldn't be running these checks for each test. Using test argument names to determine which fixtures are injected is a core component of `pytest`, and littering each test which uses fixtures with `assert isinstance(my_fixture, MyFixtureType)` for each fixture is redundant.

`pytest-django` is already testing that the [`client`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/blob/f55c7099155703e381f3b5890130c04b906af154/tests/test_fixtures.py#L25) and [`rf`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/blob/f55c7099155703e381f3b5890130c04b906af154/tests/test_fixtures.py#L51) fixtures are of the correct type:

```py
def test_client(client):
    assert isinstance(client, Client)
...
def test_rf(rf):
    assert isinstance(rf, RequestFactory)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

As you've passed the fixture as param to the test method, if you got the fixture name correctly, you don't have to check anything.

Here's an example:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')                                                                                                                                                                            
def factory():                                                                                                                                                                                              
    return RequestFactory(HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')                                                                                                                                        

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')                                                                                                                                                                            
def client():                                                                                                                                                                                               
    return Client(HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')
```

Now, in your test method you can take one or both of the fixtures and work with them e.g.:

```
def test_foo(client):
    # Do stuff     

def test_bar(factory):
    # Do stuff
```

**Original answer:**

You can check for the type of the input fixture using `isinstance`.

```
from django.test import RequestFactory, Client
```

Inside the test method test for `Client`:

```
if isinstance(client, Client):
    # This is a Client instance
```

Similarly for `RequestFactory`:

```
if instance(rf, RequestFactory):
    # This is a RequestFactory instance
```

Comment: That's a bit odd, testing your dep in a dep injection. The API is the same https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.RequestFactory but the behavior of a `Client` is different than a `RequestFactory`. Thus, I'd have to make these instance checks on every test...

Comment: @nz_21 So why test? You're passing them as fixtures and if you've got the params correctly, you don't need to check anything.

Comment: @heeemy so it all boils down to how I *name* a given fixture? A quick run seem to indicate that is indeed the case...that's some magic right there

Comment: @nz_21 Yes, I've edited my answer to add an example.